# Code for summary-method in mirt package

Tags: r

I need to see the code for the summary function which is used in **mirt** package to see the factor loading matrix.

I have tried `edit(summary)` which in return giving me this

```
function (object, ...) 
standardGeneric("summary")
```

which is not very helpful for me. How can I see the code for `summary`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`summary`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/summary.html) is a [generic function](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/OO-essentials.html#s4). So you need to see the class-specific method for whatever type of object you're trying to `summary`-ize. E.g., see `summary.lm` (for `lm` objects). You don't specify the object class you're working with, so it's impossible to say what specific `summary` function you need to look at.

UPDATE: These are s4 generics, which is a bit more complicated than `summary.lm`, which is s3. Some quick googling reveals that you can see the relevant s4 methods on the package's Github page. The contents of `summary` will depend on what specific class you're looking at (and there appear to be four classes in the package):

- [Exploratory](https://github.com/philchalmers/mirt/blob/55a8c1f0bacffafb589dd3caf2741b195cbfa65d/R/Exploratory-methods.R)
- [Mixed](https://github.com/philchalmers/mirt/blob/b06918f9bc33c063e959a27bf0f16d1af8202f4e/R/Mixed-methods.R)
- [Confirmatory](https://github.com/philchalmers/mirt/blob/b06918f9bc33c063e959a27bf0f16d1af8202f4e/R/Confirmatory-methods.R)
- [MultipleGroup](https://github.com/philchalmers/mirt/blob/c7932fa34c72954474f4c5c8537ae727fd2dd1cb/R/MultipleGroup-methods.R)

[This question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19226816/how-can-i-view-the-source-code-for-a-function) will also be helpful for addressing these kinds of questions in general in the future.

Comment: thank you. :)
showMethods("summary")
Function: summary (package base)
object="ANY"
object="ConfirmatoryClass"
object="diagonalMatrix"
object="ExploratoryClass"
object="MixedClass"
object="mle"
object="MultipleGroupClass"
object="sparseMatrix"

suppose my object is from Confirmatory class. Now can you please tell me. how can I see the code for "summary" function

Comment: @user3755708 This depends on the class of the object you're trying to summarize. If `x` is the object you're trying to summarize (i.e., with `summary(x)`), what is the value you get from `class(x)`?

Comment: I will make it simpler.

In "mirt" package I was running following commands

R> library("mirt")
R> data <- expand.table(LSAT7)
R> (mod1 <- mirt(data, 1))
R> summary(mod1)

Now can you please tell me how can I get the code for summary here in this particular case.

Comment: @user3755708 That doesn't really help, but see my edits.